# Unable to dynamically load npm-modules in ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, hyperledger-composer

I am running into an issue using the combination of the `hyberledger-composer-common npm` module and `ionic`. Basic setting up works as expected but when i am trying to connect to the `hyperledger` network it throws the following error:

```
Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlfv1" for connection profile "Default". curmod.require is not a function-connectionManagerLoader.require is not a function-connectionManagerLoader.require is not a function-Cannot find module "."
    at connectionProfileStore.load.then (connectionprofilemanager.js:160)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
```

I am fairy new to using `ionic` and `javascript` builders so i have no clue where to look. I am guessing it has something to do with `polyfills` and the way `ionic` handles paths but i am not sure. Could anyone give me a bump in the right direction?

The application also throws a similar error while trying to instantiate the loggerclass:

```
Failed to load logger module ./winstonInjector.js: Cannot find module "."
```

The implementation is as follows:

```
//example
var loggerToUse = './winstonInjector.js';
myLogger = require(loggerToUse);
```

Which gave me the idea the issue is regarding dynamically loading modules :)

Comment: Might help to post the output from the command `npm list -g --depth=0`

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm getting the same error `Failed to load logger module ./winstonInjector.js: Cannot find module "."`