# Unable to Dynamically Load Modules in Angular 5 and Hyperledger Composer

Tags: angular, hyperledger-composer

I have built an Angular 5 application with the goal of loading a `BusinessNetworkDefinition` from a card archive.  I cannot seem to figure out how to dynamically load modules in my Angular application.  When I load the card archive file and then try to connect to a running business network via the following code, I receive an error.

```
  private fileAccepted(file: File): void {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    fileReader.onloadend = () => {
      this.cardService.importCard(fileReader.result).then((card) => {
        this.card = card;
        const connProfile = this.card.getConnectionProfile();
        this.connectionProfileManager.connectWithData(this.card.getConnectionProfile(), this.card.getBusinessNetworkName())
          .then((connection) => {
            console.log(connection);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      });
    }
```

Here is the error that this throws:

```
Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlfv1" for connection type "hlfv1". curmod.require is not a function-connectionManagerLoader.require is not a function-Cannot find module "."
    at Promise.resolve.then (connectionprofilemanager.js:144)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4760)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
    at zone.js:872
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
```

To add a bit more context to the situation, I have also received the following error on compilation with webpack:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/composer-common/lib/connectionprofilemanager.js
132:57-69 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/composer-common/lib/connectionprofilemanager.js
 @ ./node_modules/composer-common/index.js
 @ ./src/app/services/identity-card.service.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

I suspect that this has something to do with dynamically loaded modules, but I have looked at and tried all the solutions contained in the following issues/posts:

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/196
- https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3952
- [Unable to dynamically load npm-modules in ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666884/unable-to-dynamically-load-npm-modules-in-ionic)

I was hoping that someone could explain technically what is going on here and where I should look for solutions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Angular but is this something to do with your module.exports in Angular - possibly in your ./app/routes module? Have you defined routes - some resources that may help -> [NodeJs : TypeError: require(...) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007878/nodejs-typeerror-require-is-not-a-function/39444790#39444790) and Express discussion for similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758198/app-post-is-not-a-function-express-node) .

One last thing is to check also that composer npm modules were installed using npm install in your project and your package.json had the right dependencies.